# Let $X,X_i$ random variables such that $(X_n-X)^2\underset{p}{\to}0$ prove $X_i^2$ converges to $X^2$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Let $X,X_i$ random variables such that $(X_n-X)^2\underset{p}{\to}0$
> prove $X_i^2$ converges to in probability $X^2$

I've tried using the definition of converges in probability but didn't get too far
any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\eta>0$. I guess that $X$ is finite a.s. (otherwise I don't think that it's true). Therefore, there is $K>0$ s.t. $$\mathbb P\{|X|>K\}\leq \eta.$$

Let $\varepsilon >0$.
Then,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon \}&=\mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon ,|X|\leq K\}\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ +\mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon ,|X|>K\}\\
&\leq \mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon ,|X|\leq K\}+\eta.
\end{align*}

The function $f(x):=x^2$ is uniformly continuous on $[-2K,2K]$. Therefore, there is $\delta \in(0,K)$ s.t. for all $n\in\mathbb N$,  $$|f(X_n)-f(X)|>\varepsilon \implies |X_n-X|>\delta.$$

Therefore
$$\mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon ,|X|\leq K\}\leq \mathbb P\{(X_n-X)^2>\delta ^2\}\underset{n\to \infty }{\longrightarrow }0.$$

Therefore, $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon \}<\eta,$$

for all $\eta>0$, and since $\eta>0$ is unspecified, we conclude that $$  \lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P\{|X_n^2-X^2|>\varepsilon \}=0,$$
as wished.